# Adding the values contained in two tables as maps in Hive

Tags: aggregate-functions, hiveql

Lets say there are two tables

```
Table 1

XYZ | {a:1,b:2,c:3}

Table 2

XYZ | {a:2,b:6,c:1}
```

I want a hive query which can add the values contained in the maps and provide the resulting map as follows.

```
Merged Table

XYZ | {a:3,b:8,c:4}
```

Comment: I think 1st you need to explode the values using lateral view outer explode and then you need to sum it and then you need to convert it back to array or json format(Not sure).

Comment: i was looking for something like a combine from brickhouse. How does it work on maps having common keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved using below method in hive:

Consider I have 2 hive tables as sample_map1 and sample_map2.

```
select * from sample_map1;
OK
col1  col2
XYZ   {"a":10,"b":20,"c":30}

select * from sample_map2;
OK
col1  col2
XYZ   {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

Query:

```
select a.col1,str_to_map(concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat(a.exp_col2_k,':',a.sum_col2))))
from(
select m.col1,exp_col2_k as exp_col2_k,sum(exp_col2_v) as sum_col2
from
(select m1.*
from sample_map1 m1 join sample_map2 m2
on(m1.col1=m2.col1)
union all
select m2.*
from sample_map1 m1 join sample_map2 m2
on(m1.col1=m2.col1)
)m
lateral view explode(m.col2)ex as exp_col2_k,exp_col2_v
group by m.col1,exp_col2_k
)a
group by col1;
```

Explanation for the above query:

```
1.Here lateral view explode has been used to explode the map column,which explodes the map into separate rows as key-value pairs.
2.Then sum function is used to find the sum of value column.
3.Used concat function to form a key value pair (key:value).
4.Next collect_list function is used to collect the key-value pairs as array.
5.Then concat_ws function is used to convert the array into string with comma separator.
6.At last str_to_map function is used to convert the string to map.
```

Hope this solution helps you.

Thanks